# Has any mission to Titan tested the idea of producing electricity from Saturn's magnetic field?

Tags: mission-design, power, future-missions, saturn, titan

From an answer to Astronomy SE question [How does Titan maintain the atmosphere](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/8345/how-does-titan-maintain-the-atmosphere)

[image: Titan in Saturn's magnetic field]

And we know the idea of generating electricity with a coil orbiting through a planet's magnetic field is sound in principle, if you've any doubts see answers to the Physics SE question [Can the Earth's magnetic field be used to generate electricity?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/65082/can-the-earths-magnetic-field-be-used-to-generate-electricity).

*Put together this suggests a potential solid state source of electricity that doesn't require any fuel that will last indefinitely.*

*For a probe on Titan's surface (perhaps one monitoring atmospheric density & composition) as little as one hour of full power & radio contact with Earth once a week or so may be adequate especially for a backup power system.*

So I was just wondering if it has either been proposed, used or tested by any [Titan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Titan_(moon)) missions to date.

Comment: The answer to the question you linked states: Electrical charge is generated through a changing magnetic field. As for whether or not the magnetic field at Titans orbit is inconsistent enough to generate magnetic flux in significant quantities at a small enough gradient for a probe to use... I'd doubt it but do not know. The gradient of a planets magnetic field is not 100% homogenous at a macro level. At a micro level- it is essentially homogenous.

Comment: If any of that is false, feel free to correct me, it's just info I gathered from your linked question and small amounts of personal knowledge.

Comment: You don't get free electrical energy by moving a coil through a magnetic field. A changing magnetic field is necessary to generate current in the coil and the orbital speed will be reduced when kinetic energy is transformed into electrical energy.

Comment: @Uwe do you think it's an appropriate question to ask how "the orbital speed will be reduced when kinetic energy is transformed into electrical energy" mathematically? Because the physics questions claim this with no basis, yet I completely believe it due to conservation laws and the fact that this may "push against" the field, for lack of better knowledge or words. P.S. sorry about the comment spam, I am very interested in this Q's math.

Comment: @Uwe : Surely the magnetic field of Saturn that Titan moves through isn't entirely the same at all points & Titan's orbit isn't 'completely' un-eccentric, which can only exaggerate (if only a bit) any fluctuations : When the coil in question is sat on a body with the mass & momentum of Titan then any _"orbital speed ~ reduced when kinetic energy is transformed into electrical energy"_ must be negligible past the point of consideration.

Comment: @MagicOctopusUrn : I should have perhaps first asked **if** current knowledge of Saturn's magnetic field suggested this might be plausible, didn't occur to me it might not be though.

Comment: If Titan moves through the magnetic field of Saturn, you get only very small and slow changes of the magnetic field and the field is weak anyway compared to the magnetic field within an electric generator. A coil of gigantic size is necessary to get  some electrical energy. It would not be worth it.

Comment: @Uwe : ^ Bearing in mind that Titan's orbit of Saturn is 16 days (iirc) does that all still hold?

Comment: What is one cycle in 16 days compared to 50 or 60 cycles (of the European or American power grid) per second? The ratio is about 1 to 69 million.

Comment: @Uwe : Not the point though is it, we wouldn't be after that kind of power generation would we, enough to keep a probe up & running indefinitely for 1 hour a week with occasional radio contact, would be more than enough for any purpose we might have there at this time.

Answer (score 4):

To my knowledge no mission has attempted to generate electricity from Titan/Saturn's magnetic fields (or Jupiter's for that matter), a list of missions to-date includes:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pioneer_11
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voyager_1
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voyager_2
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cassini%E2%80%93Huygens

Planned missions include:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dragonfly_(spacecraft)

None of these make mention of generating electric energy from magnetic fields.

Comment: Hope you don't mind, but I did research on all missions (planned or historical) to Saturn and added them to your answer. If you deem the edit not helpful, feel free to revert. +1 for a straight-forward answer though :).